# return negative cycle with networkx

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx, bellman-ford

I'm playing around with `networkx` and noticed that `bellman_ford` algorithm does not return negative cycle, it raises `unbounded exception` instead.

How can I return the first negative cycle instead of an exception?

```
import networx as nx
def find_path(digraph, start="USD"): 
    path = nx.bellman_ford(digraph, start) 
    return path
```

In addition, I'm testing arbitrage trading with bellman_ford

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

That's because the [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) algorithm returns a shortest path for all nodes from a single source. However, if any negative-cycles exist, there is no shortest path from the source vertex to all nodes (Each node in that cycle for example has no shortest path to, since you can just iterate the cycle once more and get a lower weighted path).

What you could probably do is use [nx.simple_cycles](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html). What it does is return a generator of simple cycles, i.e distinct cycles in the graphs without repetitions of nodes (Except the first and the last of course).
Then, you could just iterate through the output generated and check for negative cycles.

I guess it would look something like this:

```
#import networx as nx
import networkx as nx
def find_path(digraph, start="USD"):
    try:
        path = nx.bellman_ford(digraph, start) 
        return path
    except NetworkXUnbounded:
        cycles = nx.simple_cycles(digraph)
        for cycle in cycles:
            print cycle  # do whatever you prefer here of course
```

I haven't tried it on my end.

Answer (score 1):

So, modifying Or Dinari's code to work with an arbitrary weight function, like the rest of networkx...

```
def negative_cycle(g, weight_func=burns_advanced):
    n = len(g.nodes())
    d = defaultdict(lambda: 10000)
    p = defaultdict(lambda: -1)
    x = -1

    for i in range(n):
        for u, v in g.edges():
            weight = weight_func(u, v, g[u][v])
            if d[u] + weight < d[v]:
                d[v] = d[u] + weight
                p[v] = u
                x = v

    if x == -1:
        print('No negative cycle')
        return None

    for i in range(n):
        x = p[x]

    cycle = []
    v = x

    while True:
        cycle.append(v)
        if v == x and len(cycle) > 1:
            break
        v = p[v]

    return list(reversed(cycle))
```

Works like a charm! I'll give you the bounty anyway since the reference is really what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Bellman-Ford for that. Here I adapted the code from [finding-negative-cycle-in-graph](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/finding-negative-cycle-in-graph.html) to python and added a running example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


def getW(edge):
    return edge[2]['weight']


def getNegativeCycle(g):
    n = len(g.nodes())
    edges = list(g.edges().data())
    d = np.ones(n) * 10000
    p = np.ones(n)*-1
    x = -1
    for i in range(n):        
        for e in edges:
            if d[int(e[0])] + getW(e) < d[int(e[1])]:
                d[int(e[1])] = d[int(e[0])] + getW(e)
                p[int(e[1])] = int(e[0])
                x = int(e[1])
    if x == -1:
        print("No negative cycle")
        return None
    for i in range(n):
        x = p[int(x)]
    cycle = []
    v = x
    while True:
        cycle.append(str(int(v)))
        if v == x and len(cycle) > 1:
            break
        v = p[int(v)]
    return list(reversed(cycle))


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('0', '1', weight=0.1)
G.add_edge('1', '2', weight=-1)
G.add_edge('2', '3', weight=-0.3)
G.add_edge('3', '0', weight=-0.4)
G.add_edge('4', '3', weight=0.7)
G.add_edge('4', '5', weight=0.9)
G.add_edge('3', '5', weight=-5)

cycle = getNegativeCycle(G)
```

this will output a negative cycle:

```
cycle
Out[68]: ['2', '3', '0', '1', '2']
```

**Note** that I am using numbered vertices, for simplicity (array locations).